# How to parallelize complicated for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have a complicated `for` loop which contains multiple operations for multiple records in a loop. The loop looks like this:

```
for i,j,k in zip(is,js,ks):
    #declare multiple lists.. like
    a = []
    b = []
    #...
    if i:
        for items in i:
            values = items['key'].split("--")
            #append the values to the declared lists
            a.append(values[0])
            b.append(values[1])
    # also other operations with j and k where are is a list of dicts. 
    if "substring" in k:
        for k, v in j["key"].items():
            l = "string"
            t = v
    else:
        for k, v in j["key2"].items():
            l = k
            t = v

            # construct an object with all the lists/params
            content = {
                'sub_content': {
                    "a":a,
                    "b":b,
                    .
                    .
                }
            }

            #form a tuple. We are interested in this tuple.
            data_tuple = (content,t,l)
```

Considering the above `for` loop, how do I parallelize it? I've looked into multiprocessing but I have not been able to parallelize such a complex loop. I am also open to suggestions that might perform better here including parallel language paradigms like OpenMP/MPI/OpenACC.

Comment: Careful with naming a variable `is`, because it's already a Python statement.

Comment: I ran into that while setting up the tests :-)

Comment: @Guimoute the variables I have changed in the post. Otherwise, the names are according to their relevance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) library. As noted in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463266/992432) you should figure out if you need multi-processing or multi-threading.

**Bottom Line**: If you need multi-threading you should use multiprocessing.dummy. If you are only doing CPU intensive tasks with no IO/dependencies then you can use multiprocessing.

> multiprocessing.dummy is exactly the same as multiprocessing module,
>   but uses threads instead (an important distinction - use multiple
>   processes for CPU-intensive tasks; threads for (and during) IO):

#### Set up the zip object

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

n = 2000
xs = np.arange(n)
ys = np.arange(n) * 2
zs = np.arange(n) * 3

zip_obj = zip(xs, ys, zs)
```

#### Simple example function

```
def my_function(my_tuple):
    iv, jv, kv = my_tuple
    return f"{str(iv)}-{str(jv)}-{str(kv)}"
```

#### Set up the multi-threading.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(4)
data_tuple = pool.map(my_function, zip_obj)
```

#### Your full example

```
def my_function(my_tuple):
    i, j, k = my_tuple
    #declare multiple lists.. like
    a = []
    b = []
    #...
    if (i):
        for items in i:
            values = items['key'].split("--")
            #append the values to the declared lists
            a.append(values[0])
            b.append(values[1])
     #also other ooperations with j and k where are is a list of dicts. 
     if ("substring" in k):
           for k, v in j["key"].items():
               l = "string"
               t = v
      else:
           for k, v in j["key2"].items():
               l = k
               t = v
    #construct an object called content with all the lists/params like
           content = {
                'sub_content': {
                  "a":a,
                  "b":b,
                  .
                  .
                }
            }
    #form a tuple. We are interested in this tuple.
    return (content,t,l)


from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(4)
zip_obj = zip(is,js,ks)
data_tuple = pool.map(my_function, zip_obj)
# Do whatever you need to do w/ data_tuple here
```

Comment: Can you add an example demonstrating the same?

Comment: @Eswar - Please test this and see if the return statement `return (content,t,l)` is correct

Comment: Does the pool return something if the my_funtion doesn't return anything? can I just run pool.map(my_func,zip_object)?